# What is the problematic part in finding the center of mass of one eight of a sphere in this construction?

Tags: definite-integrals, physics, surface-integrals

> Find the centre of mass of that portion of homogeneous hemispherical
>   surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ lying above the first quadrant in the
>   xy-plane

I did the necessary calculation and the transformations of the axis to the spherical coordinates and last step was the following:

$$\vec{r}_{cm} = \frac{\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} [(\sin\phi \cos\theta)\hat x + (\sin\phi \sin\theta )\hat y + (\cos\phi)\hat z ] a^3 \sin\phi d\phi d\theta}{\frac{\pi a^2}{2}}$$

The x and the y coordinates of $\vec{r}_{CM}$ are correct, but not the z coordinate.I mean with this construction r becomes

$$\vec{r}_{CM}=a/2 (\hat x + \hat y) + 2a(\hat z).$$

I couldn't find where is my mistake.

Comment: Your integral corresponds to the region $0\leq\theta\leq\pi/2$, $0\leq\phi\leq\pi/2$. Have you drawn out that region?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, as far as I see, there is still no problem in that.

Comment: Ahh, I see. (The title of your question says 'one quarter of a sphere', but it looks like the body refers to an eighth, the positive xyz octant?)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You are right, I mix then up.Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Your integral for the center of mass is wrong.  You've 'popped out' $\hat{x}$, etc. but those aren't constant vectors; they depend in an essential way on $\rho, \theta, \phi$ and that needs to be accounted for in your integration.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I constructed my setup by assuming they they are constant unit vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem setup looks fine; I would just check the arithmetic at each step.

For the $z$ coordinate, we first have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} (\cos\phi) a^3 \sin\phi\, d\phi = \frac12a^3.$$

Next,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}  \frac12a^3 = \frac{\pi a^3}{4}.$$

Finally,
$$\frac{\pi a^3/4}{\pi a^2/2} = \frac a2.$$